# iOS 7 UITableView grouped style hide my cells

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have created an `UITableView` in my app programatically. I have a strange problem. I have never seen this and I think everything is alright. It seems like all the table goes down and I only can see the first row. I want to create the same `UITableView` grouped as the settings tableViews in iOS7

[image: Image app IOS 7]

But the Image in iOS 6 it is strange too.. I have written a NSLog and the height is 132 = 3 items * 44 height cell.
[image: Image app iOS 6]

Here it is the code.

```
static float x = 10.0;
static float y = 80.0;
static NSString *CategoryCellIdentifier     = @"CategoryCell";
static float kHeightCell                    = 44.0;

@interface LKLHomeViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *itemsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *categoryTableView;

@end

@implementation LKLHomeViewController
@synthesize itemsArray;
@synthesize categoryTableView;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    // Adding tableView to self.view
    [self.view addSubview:self.categoryTableView];
}

#pragma mark - Custom getter

-(NSArray *)itemsArray
{
    if(!itemsArray){
        itemsArray = @[@"Near", @"Kind of" , @"More.."];

        return itemsArray;
    }
    return itemsArray;
}

- (UITableView *)categoryTableView
{
    //custom init of the tableview
    if (!categoryTableView) {
        CGFloat height = kHeightCell * [self.itemsArray count];
        CGFloat width  = self.view.frame.size.width  - (x*2);

        CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

        // regular table view
        categoryTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        categoryTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        categoryTableView.delegate = self;
        categoryTableView.dataSource = self;
        categoryTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [categoryTableView setScrollEnabled:NO];

        [[categoryTableView layer] setCornerRadius:5.0f];

        return categoryTableView;
    }
    return categoryTableView;

}
```

Comment: it's problem with height of table view set it to height of viewController

Comment: Why? this is not a UITableViewController. It is a ViewController with UITableViewDelegte and UITableViewDatasource

Comment: Becoz your UItableView Style is group it will only show no cell that delegate function numberOfRowsInSection in your Case it looks like calculation of height is not correct. Could check the height of tableview using break points.

Comment: If I give a bigger height to the TableView I can watch 3 cells. If I scroll up the tableView it is the same size of 3 cells